# I want to have my for loop count down using a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
step = int(input('enter a step size to count down by '))
for i in range(0,31,step):
    print(i)
```

I would like to know how to make this loop count down instead of up like it currently does. Thanks. (edit): I had previously tried swapping the start and stop values, which didn't work. Then i tried making 'step' negative int the range function which didn't work. I wasn't aware that doing both of these things together was a viable solution. Thanks to everyone who posted in response

Comment: swap start and end values and step is negative

Comment: i've tried that and once i ran it and input the value i wanted, it wouldn't output the countdown

Comment: @JohannSebastianGonzalez It works e.g. `list(range(31,0,-1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the start and end value and and negate the step value

```
step = int(input('enter a step size to count down by '))
for i in range(31, 0 ,-step):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing both steps separately but it didn't occur to me to try them together